# DynamoDB many-to-many relationship model

Tags: database-design, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, many-to-many, adjacency-list

I'm trying to model a dynamo table for many to many relationships. I'll try to simplify as much as I can:

I have **trainers** and their **clients**. One trainer can have many clients and clients can belong to many trainers - kind of the classic M-M problem with dynamo. But I can't seem to get my head around it.

The access pattern is the following:

- The trainer needs to be able to get and list all of his clients
- The client needs to be able to get and update his info

Now I have two solutions in mind so far that are pretty similar and not satisfactory:

1. I keep one object for the client and a list of objects within the trainer object - if a client updates his/her info it will have to be done in several trainer objects
2. I keep one object for the client and one separate for each trainer - if a client updates his/her info it will also have to be done in several objects

I have everything in one table and no GSI's yet as per below structure

So here is my current structure:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|PK          |SK          |Attributes   |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|trainer1_id |  TRAINER   |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|trainer2_id |  TRAINER   |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|client1_id  |  CLIENT    |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|client2_id  |  CLIENT    |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|client3_id  |  CLIENT    |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
```

Alternative 1:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|PK          |SK          |Attributes   |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|trainer1_id |  TRAINER   |[CLIENTLIST] |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|client1_id  |  CLIENT    |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|client2_id  |  CLIENT    |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
|client3_id  |  CLIENT    |name, etc    |
|------------|------------|-------------|
```

Alternative 2:

```
+------------+------------+-------------------+
|PK          |SK          |Attributes         |
|------------|------------------|-------------|
|trainer1_id |  TRAINER         |name, etc    |
|------------|------------------|-------------|
|client1_id  |  CLIENT          |name, etc    |
|------------|------------------|-------------|
|client2_id  |  CLIENT          |name, etc    |
|------------|------------------|-------------|
|trainer1_id |CLIENT#client1_id |name, etc    |
|------------|------------------|-------------|
|trainer1_id |CLIENT#client2_id |name, etc    |
|------------|------------------|-------------|
...etc
```

I guess my actual question here is: What would be the correct access pattern if I want keep *one* client object with all client info but at the same time list all clients belonging to a trainer? Is this even the right approach? Apologies if something is unclear

Answer (score 2):

In general, in NoSQL DBs (in particular: DynamoDB) you need to denormalize the data much more often than in a relational DB. This simplifies the reads but makes updates/writes more complicated.

Specifically, in your case I would go with a items which contain all `client` and `trainer` details.

```
{ pk: '<some-unique-id>`, 
  clientId: '<some-unique-id>', 
  clientName: 'Bob',
  clientPhoneNumber: '...', 
  trainerId: '<some-unique-id>', 
  trainerName: 'Alice', trainerPhoneNumber: '....' }
```

The catch is that when (say) a client name is changed, you need to find all items with that client and update them. Similarly for `clientPhoneNumber`, `trainerName`, etc.

You if you want to quickly find all items associated with a given `clientId` value you need to define a global secondary index (GSI) which uses the `clientId` attribute as its partition key. A second GSI on the `trainerId` attribute will be needed for finding all items associated with a given `trainerId` value.

Finally, since your update process is not atomic (your program may stop running, due to various bugs/hardware failures/network failures, in the middle of updating the items) you will need to setup a program that fixes inconsistencies to run on regular basis. This program will find items with the same `clientId` value but with different `clientName` values. (Respectively, `trainerId`, `trainerName`). This goes to other attributes (e.g. `clientPhoneNumber`).

See further details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57665608/how-to-model-many-to-many-relationship-in-dynamodb-with-java-sdk/57672703#57672703)

Comment: This would unfortunately most likely increase the number of updates even more due to also having the trainer needing to update all of his items in case of change in the data.

Comment: I agree @Shaho , but that's the tradeoff you make in the NoSql world: the query language is usually not as powerful as SQL. Thus, you need to structure the data to fit your query. On the other hand, the NoSql DBs (and DynamoDB in particular) are  more robust and scalable and can easily incur the cost of additional write operations every time a piece of item needs to change.